# Add letter if it's duplicate C

Tags: c, string

I work on playfair cipher and I have one problem.

I need to add letter X in my string if the next letter it's duplicate. 
Example before: HELLOWORLD 
separe the string in 2 pairs (HE LL OW OR LD) and if it's duplicate add X. (I need to add X only if the pair is duplicate.
After: HE LX LO WO RL D -> HELXLOWORLD

My code:

```
for (j = 0, i = 0; i < len_text; i++, j++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        if (my_text[i] == my_text[i+1]) {
            text_x[j] = my_text[i];
            i++;
            text_x[j+1] = 'X';

            j++;
        }
        else {
            text_x[j] = my_text[i];

        }   
    }
    else if (i % 2 != 0) {
        text_x[j] = text[i];
    }   
}
```

My code don't works normally. Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The question is: "I have managed to cobble together some code that does not work. Can you debug my code for me?" Hint, such questions tend not be accepted very well on here.

Comment: Don't work 100%... Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of converting `HELLOWORLD` to `HELXLOWORLD`.

Comment: First you make pairs of two. HE LL OW OR LD and if in this pair the next one is duplicate you add the letter X. Thats all.

Comment: And what happens when `X` is already present? How to distinguish `HELLOWORLD` ==> `HELXLOWORLD` from `HELXLOWORLD` ==> `HELXLOWORLD`?

Comment: Nothing. But if it's duplicate, add another one.
Example: TAXXXI -> TA XX XI -> now you add one x in XX -> TA XX XX I -> TAXXXXI

Example2: TAXI -> TA XI -> TAXI (nothing here)

Example3: TAXXI -> TA XX I -> add one x in XX, because XX are in pair -> TAXXXI

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you could do something like this. The way you're currently doing it looks like it could potentially go out of bounds with `i`. Make sure that `text_x` is a buffer big enough to hold these extra chars you're inserting (i.e. `len_text + len_text / 2` at max).

```
for (j = 0, i = 0; i < len_text - 1; i+=2, j+=2) {
    text_x[j] = my_text[i];
    if (my_text[i] == my_text[i+1]) {
        text_x[j+1] = 'X';
        j++;
    } 
    text_x[j+1] = my_text[i+1];
}
```

Comment: Perfect Gavin, thank you so much!